# Download xpi files in PHP

Tags: php, xpi

I'm working on project that should create link to download xpi file.

T his is my php code to download file:

```
$fileName = 'file.xpi';
$size = filesize($fileName);

$fp = fopen($fileName, "rb");
$content = fread($fp, $size);
fclose($fp);

header("Content-length: ".$size);
header("Content-type: application/x-xpinstall");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName.";" );
echo $content;
```

This code work's fine, but the downloaded file is my problem.. when i run, Firefox show this error message:

> This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.

Both files (that one on server and that one downloaded) have the same information.

## file on server

Sive : 14.7 MB (15,509,809 bytes)

Sive on Disk : 14.7 MB (15,511,552 bytes)

## download file

Sive : 14.7 MB (15,509,809 bytes)

Sive on Disk : 14.7 MB (15,511,552 bytes)

What should I do?

Comment: Is the original file working?

Comment: Perhaps better: use [fpassthu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). That way, you don't have to load the entire file in a string.

Comment: Is the file you want to download a working Firefox Add-On? Because Firefox will try to install files with the ending .xpi

Comment: @ Peter Noble yes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open downloaded file in some kind of text editor like Notepad and check if there are not any plain text PHP-related errors at the beginning of the file.

Comment: tanx, i forgot to check files in notepad! exist break line at top of the page i create and that one 'Enter' joined to file. exactly to the point.